# How to check mail is sent or not in magento?

Tags: email, magento

My code:

```
            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($templateId);
            $senderMail = $order->getCustomerEmail();
            $senderName  = $order->getCustomerName();
            $receiverMail = Mage::helper('orderattachments')->getEmailAddress();
            $receiverName = Mage::helper('orderattachments')->getName();
            $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("Order Attachments_ " . $orderId);
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderMail, $storeId);
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName, $storeId);
            $emailTemplate->send($receiverMail,$receiverName, $post);
```

How to check mail is sent or not ?

```
  if(!$emailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
            throw new Exception('Not Sent');
        }
```

is that correct way to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 if(!$emailTemplate->send($receiverMail,$receiverName, $post)) {
        throw new Exception('Not Sent');
    }
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation, why this solves the problem